# MySQL Workbenchで問題ないクエリーをPHPで実行すると構文エラーになります。

Tags: php, mysql

MySQL Workbenchでは問題なく抽出できるのですが、PHPで実行するとSyntaxエラーが発生します。
また、PHPでエラーとなったクエリーをMySQL Workbenchに張り付けるとやはり問題なく動作します。
クエリーは以下となりますが、0件データも抽出したいためLeftJoinをしています。
ご教示いただけますと幸いです。

```
select distinct t1.value , ifnull(t2.count, 0) as count 
from( select value FROM sa.tbl_textdata_attribute ta 
inner join sa.tbl_textdata_header th on ta.header_id = th.id where ta.analysis_id = '1000' and th.name= '商品カテゴリ') as t1 
left join( select value, count(*) as count from sa.TBL_TEXTDATA_ATTRIBUTE TA inner join sa.TBL_TEXTDATA_HEADER TH on TA.header_id = TH.id where TA.analysis_id = '1000' 
and TH.name= '商品カテゴリ' and textdata_id in ( select textdata_id from sa.TBL_WORDVOLUME where delete_Flg = 0 and analysis_id = 1000 and ****条件が続く****) 
group by textdata_id) group by value )as t2 on t1.value = t2.value order by t1.value
```

phpのコードは以下です。
クエリーを分割しているのは、middleだけ使うケースもあるためです。

```
    function getPositiveRate($aid, $category){

        if($category){

            $query_first = "
            select distinct t1.value , ifnull(t2.count, 0) as count
            from( select value FROM tbl_textdata_attribute ta 
            inner join tbl_textdata_header th on ta.header_id = th.id 
            where 
            ta.analysis_id = '".$aid."' and th.name= '".$category_name."') as t1
            left join(
            select value, count(*) as count from TBL_TEXTDATA_ATTRIBUTE TA
            inner join TBL_TEXTDATA_HEADER TH on TA.header_id = TH.id 
            where 
            TA.analysis_id = '".$aid."' and TH.name= '".$category."' and 
            textdata_id in (";

            $query_end = ") group by value )as t2 on t1.value = t2.value order by t1.value;";
        }

        $query_middle = "
        select textdata_id from TBL_WORDVOLUME
        where
        delete_Flg = 0 and analysis_id = ".$aid." and (
        *****条件が続く****
        )
        group by textdata_id";


        $sql = $query_first.$query_middle.$query_end;

        list($cnt, $res) = $this->db->DBrsSqlGet($sql);

        return $rtn;
    }
```

PHPのエラーは以下となります。

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\' at line 113 sql=[ select distinct t1.value ****クエリーが続く。
```

Comment: PHP で実行するとエラーになるのであれば、PHP のコードも質問中に追記してください。また、"Workbench" は "MySQL Workbench" の事でしょうか？

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

''でシンタックスエラーとなっているため、''が利用されている箇所はないのでしょうか。
$query_middleの*****条件が続く****箇所も確認してみてください。

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/ja/string-literals.html

Comment: ありがとうございます。解決いたしました。
クエリーの末尾に；が入っていました。
ここにPHPのソースを張り付けたこととコメントで気付きを得ることができました。
$query_end = ") group by value )as t2 on t1.value = t2.value order by t1.value;";

Answer (score -1):

コードを書く時、字下げはとても必要なことなので忘れないで下さい。字下げの標準を守るとコードが読みやすくなります。以下のリンクを参考にして下さい。

[https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse154/18sp/18sp-data/documents/styleguide/sql/spacing-indentation-sql.html#:~:text=Indentation%20for%20the%20CREATE%20TABLE%20statement%20should%20be%20consistent.,except%20for%20the%20last%20line](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse154/18sp/18sp-data/documents/styleguide/sql/spacing-indentation-sql.html#:%7E:text=Indentation%20for%20the%20CREATE%20TABLE%20statement%20should%20be%20consistent.,except%20for%20the%20last%20line)).